# ComboBox in ListBox doesn't update IsChecked properly

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have made a CheckedListBox using the following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst_checkBoxList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and am populating it using the following:

```
public List<CheckedListItem> listItems = new List<CheckedListItem>();

public class CheckedListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public CheckedListItem(int id, string name, bool ischecked)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        IsChecked = ischecked;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listItems.Add(new CheckedListItem(0, "item 1", false));
    listItems.Add(new CheckedListItem(0, "item 2", false));
    listItems.Add(new CheckedListItem(0, "item 3", false));
    listItems.Add(new CheckedListItem(0, "item 4", false));
    lst_checkBoxList.ItemsSource = listItems;
    listItems[0].IsChecked = true; //This correctly sets the first CheckBox as checked.
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listItems[0].IsChecked = true; //This does not affect the CheckBox, despite changing the value it is bound to.
}
```

If I change the data behind one of the CheckBoxes immediately after setting the ItemsSource, the CheckBox is ticked accordingly, but if I try to change the value anywhere else in the code the CheckBox remains unchecked...can anyone help me work out why?

Comment: Just keep the binding code (top 5 lines of button1_Click) in Window_Loaded (Window.Loaded) event. I'm sure buttton1 also stops working, I mean first elment being checked will stop on button1 click. CUrrently it is happening because of a race condition, first elment is set even before control is bound (in runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify the control that the property it is bound to has been updated, by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in `CheckedListItem`:

```
public class CheckedListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _IsChecked;
    public bool IsChecked 
    { 
        get { return _IsChecked; }
        set 
        {
            _IsChecked = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks, although I'm annoyed that it was something so simple that I hadn't thought of...oh well, lesson learnt!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface on your CheckedListItem class and then notify on any property changes.